# How to find the period of a given signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, periodic

I'm new to Signal Analysis. I have a manually generated Signal from a Gyroscope, which looks like in the picture below and I need to extract the X-Values for each period. Is there some technique to automatically  find the X-Axis Values, where the period of the Signal repeats? If not, how would one proceed to somehow find the period?

[image: Signal]

Comment: You'll want to look up *autocorrelation*. It's a simple formula, it gives a very intuitive graph if plotted, and it can very easily be programmatically analyzed for signal periodicities!

Comment: See : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpoQs7STDpI